# What values do root_x_return and root_y_return in XQueryPointer function represent?

Tags: x11, pixel, screen-resolution

This is just a dummy confirmation question but I really want to make sure the values I receive from calling the function `XQueryPointer` are in *pixels* for the X and Y screen coordinates.

```
extern Bool XQueryPointer(
Display*        /* display */,
Window      /* w */,
Window*     /* root_return */,
Window*     /* child_return */,
int*        /* root_x_return */,
int*        /* root_y_return */,
int*        /* win_x_return */,
int*        /* win_y_return */,
unsigned int*       /* mask_return */
);
```

This is because I will need to perform some operations once I get the whole resolution of my screen using the following functions, i.e. I'll filter out some pixels from the entire screen but need to know the values returned by `XQueryPointer` are also pixels.

```
xVal = DisplayWidth(display, screen_number);
yVal = DisplayHeight(display, screen_number);
```

I'm assuming `root_x_return` and `root_y_return` are in pixels. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  From the [Xlib documentation](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/introduction/overview.html):

> Each window and pixmap has its own coordinate system. The coordinate system has the X axis horizontal and the Y axis vertical with the origin [0, 0] at the upper-left corner. Coordinates are integral, in terms of pixels, and coincide with pixel centers. For a window, the origin is inside the border at the inside, upper-left corner.

Comment: Thanks, I already tested it. The values are pixels as I expected.